# Express Route not downloading file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This may be a low hanging fruit question but I am trying to use res.download in a router.post route like so

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
var csv;
csv = utils.convertToCsv(req.body);
console.log(csv);
res.download('./temp/csv/' + csv + '.csv', csv + '.csv', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:' + err);
    } else {
        console.log(res.headersSent) //True
        console.log('Success!!') //Success!!
        }
     });
});
```

I suspect that my file is not downloading because it is in a router.post route.  Is this correct or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Let Express set the correct headers. Remove res.set and then try.

Comment: @sam100rav Thanks for your suggestion, but still nothing.

Comment: Then use res.sendFile instead of res.download. but if you want to use res,download use res.download('./temp/csv/' + csv + '.csv', 'some_name.csv', function(err) {console.log(err)}); Now, look into the error.

Comment: @sam100rav I updated my code with the changes you suggested and it prints out True for res.headersSent and Success on that console.log.  It seems like it is working, just not downloading the file.